# How to use right to left languages in fmx grids

Tags: grid, firemonkey, register-transfer-level

What is the best way in FMX to create a grid that supports bidimode and righttoleft languages
I have tried fmxrtl but it has many errors
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app only for Windows ? **If yes,** I use a function to detect if it's a Bidi string and then use TTextLayout [my test here](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1871954/environnements-developpement/delphi/composants-fmx/colonne-grille-arabe-rtl/)
Else, try to use SKIA4Delphi (XE7+)[Supporting right to left](https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi#right-to-left)

I test an Android little app [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc6Mx.png)

```
procedure TForm1.Grid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer;
  const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
begin
if (Column.Index=1) AND (Row>=1)
then begin
      Canvas.Fill.Color:=TAlphaColors.Red;
      Canvas.FillText(Bounds,Value.ToString,false,1,[TFillTextFlag.RightToLeft],TTextAlign.Leading);
end
else Column.DefaultDrawCell(Canvas,bounds,row,value,state);
end;
```